# Python to search (text) files recursively and perform user-id deletion

Tags: python, pandas

```
OS: Ubuntu-18.04lts
Python version - 3.6.9
```

Excel report `data.xlsx` i have is,

[image]

I have many text files under `/home/user/excel/report/`directory and inside its sub-directories. Some of the text files along with path given below for reference.

```
/home/user/excel/report/file01.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/file02.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/filepath/file03.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-2/file04.txt
```

The filename of the text files are in excel sheet's `B` column. For each row, i need to a search the text file as per `B` column and need to look the `User-ID` in `D` column, if `user-id` exists in that particular row matched text file then user-id need to be removed from that text file, Same need to perform recursively.

Currently i below python code I'm using.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))

for file in d:
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

Error:

```
$ python3.6 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt", "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/excel/report/file03.txt'
```

Still script is look at `/home/user/excel/report/`directory only. Whereas `file03.txt` is present inside `/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/filepath/` directory, Need help to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you break up this job into tasks and solve one problem at a time. Step 1, find the location of a file by name? Write a function that can do that, then move on to "edit out a specific username from a specific line of a specific file" (function with three arguments), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash cmd `find` in python to find all the txt's paths.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

pycmd = lambda cmd: print(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True))
pycmd_output = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).strip().split('\n')

# use bash com find to find all txt file's path
os.chdir('/home/user/excel')
cmd = '''
find /home/user/excel/report/ -type f -name *.txt
'''
file_list = pycmd_output(cmd)

df_file_list = pd.Series(file_list)
file_list_name = df_file_list.str.split('/|\.').str[-2]
file_map = dict(zip(file_list_name ,df_file_list ))

    # {'file02': '/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/file02.txt',
    #  'file03': '/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/filepath/file03.txt',
    #  'file04': '/home/user/excel/report/folder-2/file04.txt',
    #  'file01': '/home/user/excel/report/file01.txt'}

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
data['file_path'] = data["File Name"].map(file_map)

# have duplicated values in `data["File Name"]`
d = data.groupby('file_path')['User-ID'].agg(list).to_dict()
for file, user_id_list in d.items():
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    for user_id in user_id_list:
        contents = contents.replace(user_id, "")
    
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(contents)
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'` - I'm using python 3.6, i think i need to use higher version to solve this. If i remove `capture_output=True` it throws following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: My python version is `Python 3.7.3`, if you can use `ipython`, you can use `pycmd_output = lambda cmd: get_ipython().getoutput(cmd, split=True)` instead.

Comment: So in `file_list = ` i need to add `pycmd_output = lambda cmd: get_ipython().getoutput(cmd, split=True)`

Comment: yes, I found `pycmd_output = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True).strip().split('\n')` can work in python3.6; `file_list = pycmd_output(cmd)`

Comment: The `For loop` first read the file. Then, remove the user-id if it exists and write back to the file? because `user-id` getting removed only in few files. From `data.xlsx` file it need to read each row.

Comment: if your `File Name` in data.xlsx has duplicates values, then your can not use `d = dict(zip(data["file_path"], data["User-ID"]))`. becasue d only map one file to one user-ID.

Comment: Actually in my `data.xlsx` file i have same `File Name` in many rows but with different `User-ID` such case could you please help me to deal.

Comment: update with `d = data.groupby('file_path')['User-ID'].agg(list).to_dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Considering

```
/home/user/excel/report/file01.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/file02.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-1/filepath/file03.txt
/home/user/excel/report/folder-2/file04.txt
```

you need first do discover where each file is located, if filenames are always unique this is relatively simple with [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). I would do:

```
import os
filepaths = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/user/excel/report"):
    for fname in filenames:
        filepaths[fname] = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
print(filepaths)
```

which should created `dict` with keys being filenames and values paths to them. Then when you need to interact with file named `"X"` just use `filepaths["X"]`.

**If** following code

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))

for file in d:
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    with open(f"/home/user/excel/report/" + file + ".txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

**would work as intended if all files were inside** `/home/user/excel/report` then following should work with files which might be in subdirs

```
import os
import pandas as pd
filepaths = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/user/excel/report"):
    for fname in filenames:
        filepaths[fname] = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
d = dict(zip(data["File Name"], data["User-ID"]))

for file in d:
    with open(filepaths[file+".txt"], "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    with open(filepaths[file+".txt"], "w") as f:
        f.write(contents.replace(d[file], ""))
```

Comment: `pandas stuff` not needed?

Comment: @Kishore I just describe how to deal with getting path to file, rest of your code should remain as-is.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    filepaths[fname] = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined` for this error - this line `filepaths[fname] = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` need to be changed `filenames`?

Comment: Now showing `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(filepaths[file], "r") as f:
KeyError: 'file01'

Comment: @Kishore I fixed my code again (overlooked that your data are missing extensions)